# facing issue Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and after installing docker

Tags: 16.04, python, docker, django

I continuously get this message: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed on running this command: python manage.py runserver after installing docker in my ubuntu 16.04.

**Done with Below Points:**

1. Already Virtual environment is activated
2. Stopped Docker Services
3. Only works, when I give exact path like this: ../virtualenv/bin/python manage.py runserver

**Thanks in Advance**